# Programmatically change "Copy content in this package to a package share on distribution points" on SCCM 2012

Tags: wmi, sccm

I have a number of packages on an SCCM 2012 server. I would like to change the **"Copy content in this package to a package share on distribution points"** option on the "Data Access" tab of a package properties page using WMI?

I am familiar with manipulating SCCM objects with WMI and SCCM with .NET and VBScript, but cannot find where this option can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The properties you are looking for is ShareName(String) and ShareType(Int).

For example if you want the settings as shown in the gui below,

[image]

The settings should be changed to

```
ShareName="share1"
ShareType=2
```